# Using fraction (fr) in calc() gives "Invalid property value"

Tags: css, css-grid, css-calc

I'm trying to use `calc()` on some widths while using CSS Grid. So one thing I'm trying is this:

```
grid-template-columns: calc(1fr - 50px) calc(1fr - 50px);
```

As I want it to be two fractions, but remove 50px since that is used for padding and such. However, when doing this, Chrome says: "Invalid property value".

Can't `calc()` be used on fractions, or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An `fr` unit is not a standard length, like percentages or pixels. It represents only leftover space.

Therefore, `fr` cannot be used in `calc()` expressions.

> [**§ 7.2.3. Flexible Lengths: the `fr`
>   unit**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#fr-unit)
>
> A flexible length is a dimension with the `fr` unit, which represents
>   a fraction of the leftover space in the grid container.
>
> `fr` units are not lengths so they cannot be represented in `calc()` expressions.

But do you really need `calc()` in the first place?

`fr` applies only to remaining space, which is what is left *after* true lengths, such as width, borders, margin and padding have been factored in.

Consider using `fr` on its own. Otherwise, post a complete example with the problem.

Comment: May be the OP is asking about  grid-column-gap (or may be not)