# Is it possible to use the calc() function to determine fractions with the grid-template-columns property?

Tags: css, css-grid

I need to calculate the frames for a grid.  I wasn't getting the result I thought I should so I dumbed it down to verify it wasn't working.  Below is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
.classname {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: calc(9 - 1)fr calc(13 - 1)fr;
    /* grid-template-columns: 8fr 12fr; */
}
```

My goal is to produce the commented line of code with my grid-template-columns calculation.  Is this possible?

Comment: Not like that, but `calc( (9 - 1) * 1fr )` should work nicely. Essentially *do a calculation and convert to `fr`*

Comment: Sorry, have to correct myself. You cannot use `fr` in a `calc(..)`. Read this [SO50389130](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50390561/2015909).

Comment: Yeah, thought your solution was quick and easy but didn't work as you found out also.  But thanks for the attempt.  If you can think of a workaround I'm open to anything.  Basically I need to columns and I know the two values I want for each frame.  i.e. 8 and 12 or 40% and 60%.  After reading your link I think I"ll try calculating calcing one percentage and using 1fr for the second column.  Hope it works :)  Thanks again...

Comment: If you can use flexbox, you could calculate the `flex-grow` value for flex child elements. It doesn't have to be `1`. So `flex-grow: 8` and `flex-grow: 12` (simplified `2` and `3`) would yield the same ratio without bothering about some unit.

Comment: Your link got me to a solution.  I calculated the percentage for one column and used 1fr for the other.  Worked like a champ.  Thx...